# Integration of a function involving log in both numerator and denominator

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $$ = \int_{0}^1 \frac{x-1-\log x}{(\log x)^2}dx$$
then show that $$\int_{0}^4 \log x\,dx = 4I + 1.$$

I have found out that $\int_{0}^4 \log x\,dx = 4(\log 4-1)$. How to actually calculate $I$?

Comment: Your second integral is not right. For the primitive function look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410198/integrating-ln-x-by-parts). This means your second integral should equal $4(\ln(4)-1)$. (Integrating between bounds shouldn't have your integration variable in the result)

Comment: My first guess would be do a substitution in the first integral so the limits are from $0$ to $4$ and then somehow add both integrals in a smart way. I don't see an immediate solution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1087858/vincent-batens please check; i've edited

Comment: I have no idea how to solve it, seems that you need to find a trick. (Btw, you can mention people by writing @ and then their username)

Comment: Thank you Vincent. Could you please suggest someone, since I'm not a regular here? Thank you

Comment: Making the substitution $x=e^{-t}$
$$I=\int_{0}^1 \frac{x-1-\log x}{(\log x)^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2t}-e^{-t}+te^{-t}}{t^2}dt$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-2t}}tdt-\int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt=2\ln 2-1$$

Comment: Ah, I substituted $x=e^t$ but missed the IBP part.

Comment: After IBP I am getting $2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-2t}}tdt+\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-2t}}t$ .How to get that $\int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt$ term? Thank you.

Comment: @Svyatoslav why do we take upper limit as 1 for first integral? Thank you

Comment: It was a typo. Corrected. $$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2t}-e^{-t}+te^{-t}}{t^2}dt=-\frac{e^{-2t}-e^{-t}+te^{-t}}t\,\bigg|_{t=0}^\infty+\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}t\left(-2e^{-2t}+e^{-t}+e^{-t}-te^{-t}\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to integration by parts, Feynman's Trick can also be used to solve this integral by parametrizing the integrand as

$$I(a)=\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,\frac {x^a-a\log x-1}{\log^2 x}$$

Differentiating with respect to $a$ gives

$$I'(a)=\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,\frac {x^a-1}{\log x}$$

Differentiating again with respect to $a$ gives

$$I''(a)=\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\, x^a=\frac 1{a+1}$$

Integrating back and noting that $I'(0)=0$ gives

$$I'(a)=\log(a+1)$$

And integrating with respect to $a$ again, and noting that $I(0)=0$, gives the answer as

$$\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,\frac {x^a-a\log x-1}{\log^2 x}=(a+1)\log(a+1)-a$$

Set $a=1$ to arrive at the result

$$\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,\frac {x-\log x-1}{\log^2x}=\log 4-1$$